# Como puedo conseguir que cargue la imagen?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Me aparece el siguiente error:

> The file will not be displayed in the editor because it is either binary, very large or uses an unsupported text encoding

Este es el código:

```
$image = $request->input('digitales')[0]['image'];
$nameFile = $request->input('digitales')[0]['name'];
$typeFile = $request->input('digitales')[0]['type'];
$nameFile = str_replace(' ','_',$nameFile);
$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
$imageName = time().$nameFile;
$imageDecoded = base64_decode($image);
$f = finfo_open();
$mime_type = finfo_buffer($f, $imageDecoded, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
print_r($mime_type);
$path = storage_path(). $imageName;
File::put($path, $imageDecoded);
```

Comment: Podrias explicar tu codigo, cual es motivo de convertir tu imagen a base64?

Comment: Perdon la demora, ya pude solucionarlo, lo paso a base 64 por la forma en que lo envio y renderizo desde mi frontend